# How to write "\n" as value inside file using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am facing one issue. I need to append `\n` inside file using `node js fs module`. I am explaining my code below.

```
let endStr = '   ret= sh(script:"touch robot-rfs.yml && rm -rf robot-rfs.yml  ")\n'
           + 'nedarray = list_of_neds.split("\n")';

fs.writeFileSync(`${process.env['root_dir']}/uploads/Jenkinsfile`, endStr);
```

Here my expected output should be like below after file writing.

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
ret= sh(script:"touch robot-rfs.yml && rm -rf robot-rfs.yml  ")
nedarray = list_of_neds.split("\n")
```

But I am getting the output like below.

```
ret= sh(script:"touch robot-rfs.yml && rm -rf robot-rfs.yml  ")
   nedarray = list_of_neds.split("
   ")
```

Here due to `\n` inside `split` its taking to new line. I need to write with `\n` without any line break inside the file means `nedarray = list_of_neds.split("\n")` should be written directly in the file. Can anyone give the help to resolve this issue ?

Comment: backslashes inside a string literal need to be escaped if you want them to be literal backslashes. So `'\\n'` will be a character string with 2 characters.

Comment: @trincot - Did you mean a *two* character string? The backslash, and the `n`?